# Distinct difference between Azure Databricks and Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure

Can someone explain the distinct difference between these two products in all major aspects? As far as I am aware from reading the official documents, both could host database systems and provide data cleaning pipeline? Both are on cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Databricks:

> Azure Databricks is an Apache Spark-based analytics platform optimized
>   for the Microsoft Azure cloud services platform. Designed with the
>   founders of Apache Spark, Databricks is integrated with Azure to
>   provide one-click setup, streamlined workflows, and an interactive
>   workspace that enables collaboration between data scientists, data
>   engineers, and business analysts.

Synapse Analytics:

> Azure Synapse is a limitless analytics service that brings together
>   enterprise data warehousing and Big Data analytics. It gives you the
>   freedom to query data on your terms, using either serverless on-demand
>   or provisioned resources—at scale. Azure Synapse brings these two
>   worlds together with a unified experience to ingest, prepare, manage,
>   and serve data for immediate BI and machine learning needs

they do overlap to some extent, but they are not the same thing. Databricks is pretty much managed Apache Spark, whereas Synapse Analytics is managed SQL Data Warehouse.